# Function does not output correct maximum value

Tags: python, function, for-loop, max

I would like to find the maximum value z and find its i and j values at z maximum.

I tried the code using def function and did not get the correct maximum z value and its i and j values.

Below is my code:

```
maxi = 0
def i_j ():
    global maxi
    for i in range (1, 5):
        for j in range (1, 5):
            z = i + j
            print(z)
            if z > maxi:
                maxi = z
                return i, j
            j += 1
        i += 1
print ("Maximum: {}".format(maxi))
x, y = i_j()
print ("i at max:", x)
print ("j at max:", y)
```

The output of the Python code:

```
Maximum: 0
2
i at max: 1
j at max: 1
```

Kindly help me, many thanks.

Comment: output is exactly what you should expect you return after going into each loop once as maxi is 0 and you check z > maxi then return and end function

Comment: if you loop the range, you dont need to increase j after each loop as it is overwritten in the next loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning too early, this means you leave the function the first time that `z>maxi` is true, which means in the very first iteration.

Also, there are other mistakes that commenters pointed out:

- maxi doesn't make much sense to print before calling the function
- the for loop automatically increases the loop variables (or rather, iterates through the list that is `range(1,5,1)` and thus the incrementation doesn't actually do anything because it gets overwritten in the next step)

This is how it should look:

```
def i_j ():
    maxi = 0
    maxi_i = 0
    maxi_j = 0
    for i in range (1, 5, 1):
        for j in range (1, 5, 1):
            z = i+j
            print ("{}".format(z))
            if z > maxi:
                maxi = z
                maxi_i = i
                maxi_j = j
    return (maxi, maxi_i, maxi_j)

maxi, x, y = i_j ()
print ("Maximum: {}".format(maxi))
print ("i at max: {}".format(x))
print ("j at max: {}".format(y))
```

Comment: Thank you, dear. I see my problem, and your solution is superb. :)